# Form not saving - form.is_valid() returning false

Tags: django, django-forms

Below is all my models. Basically this is an auction website

```
class Item(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ask = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    closes = models.DateTimeField()

class Bid(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

This is the form:

```
class itemform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields =['name','description','image','category','ask','closes']
```

View for saving the form:

```
def createitem(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form= itemform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/items') 
    else:    
        form = itemform()
        return render(request, 'app/create.html', {'form':form})
```

create.html

```
{% extends 'app/layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p}}
        <button type ="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: So So where's the question? If you're looking for a place to post code without context, you should try services like Pastebin, Hastebin etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your view slightly so that you only redirect when the form is valid. When the form is not valid, you should re-render the form.

```
def createitem(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form= itemform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/items') 
    else:    
        form = itemform()
    return render(request, 'app/create.html', {'form':form})
```

This way, you will see the form's error messages, which should help you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: this is the error : The view app.views.createitem didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Comment: The code above would not return that error, because It always `returns render(...)` at the end. Check your indentation.